# How to render webpack in react app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I got my webpack to bundle and produce a bundle.js file, but when i run dev on it and go to localhost:8080 it brings me to this screen

[image]

Which seems to be a bundle of a few of the files.

Here is my package.json. Do i need to make any modifications to the scripts in this page, or is everything seem good?

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.5",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "gh-pages": "^1.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.11",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "web-dev-server": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy": "npm run build&&gh-pages -d build",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "homepage": "https://jdiperi88.github.io",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
  }
}
```

Here is my webpack.config

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      { 
        test: /\.css$/, 
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader" 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.png$/, 
        loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.(pdf|jpg)$/, 
        loader: "file-loader" 
      },
      { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, 
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }

    ]
  },
};
```

How do I make it render the application?

Comment: Where is your `index.html` file? And are you importing your `bundle.js` on it?

Answer (score 0):

inside your index.html file add:

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```